# How to specify meta parameters in search query

Tags: python, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using Elasticsearch 2.2 and the corresponding python api. I can query like

```
res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
```

that is good. Now there are also some meta parameters that we can specify with the query, as shown on

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_parameters_5

so basically, i want to execute a query like

```
url = 'http://localhost:9200/tesIndex/test/_search?from=%d&q=FieldA=ABC or FieldA=PQR'%start

result =  requests.get(url).json()
```

how would i specify this query using the elasticsearch python api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just pass them as keyword parameters:

```
res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}},  from_=20, size=100, _source=False)
```

Reference: http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/2.2.0/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search